problem when call zustand create in closure
i try to create a store in a closure, here is my code
export const usePaginationData = (requestMethod) =>
    create((set, get) => ({
        data: [],
        page: 1,
        isLoading: false,
        fetchMore: async () => {
            set({ isLoading: true })
            const newData = await requestMethod(get().page, 10);
            set((state) => ({ data: [...state.data, ...newData.data] }));
        },
    }));

then in component
const {data,isLoading,fetchMore} = usePaginationData(mockPageDataRequest)()
console.log('isLoading',isLoading);
...
return <button onClick={fetchMore}>start request</button>
...

when button clicked, the fetchMore be invoked, and isLoading has been set to true, however, the console log here always say isLoading false.
why that?

You are creating a new store on each render. Wrap it with useMemo
const usePaginationData = (requestMethod) => useMemo(() => create(...), [requestMethod])

You should not change requestMethod between the renders, it might lead to unexpected behaviour.
